# the dominance order, its order ideals, and RSK

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\Lambda_n$ denote the lattice of all integer partitions of size $n$
where the operative partial order $\lambda \unlhd \mu $ is
the *dominance order* defined by

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k \ \leq \ \mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_k
\end{equation}

for all $k \geq 1$. I'll view a partition $\lambda$ is viewed as semi-infinite, non-increasing, non-negative integer sequence $\lambda = \big(\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3 \geq \cdots \big)$ whose
size $|\lambda| = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \cdots$ is finite and equal to $n$.

**Question 1:** Does anyone know a formula for the number of
order ideals in $\Lambda_n$ ?

**Question 2:** By RSK, each partition $\lambda \in \Lambda_n$ corresponds bijectively to an involution in the symmetric group $S_n$.
In light of RSK, do the order ideals of $\Lambda_n$ correspond bijectively to a class of (interesting) elements in $S_n$ ?

**Comment:** This second Question works on a misunderstanding and is the result of some hasty reasoning. Involutions in $S_n$ are **not** in bijection with partitions $\lambda \in \Lambda_n$
but rather in bijection with standard young tableaux of partitions $\lambda \in \Lambda_n$. One way of rectifying the question is to
look at the poset $\mathcal{T}_n$ of all standard Young tableaux of all partitions $\lambda \in \Lambda_n$ under the (induced) dominance order and
ask for an interpretation of its order ideals. Recall that if we view two standard Young Tableaux $T$ and $S$ of respective shapes $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as two saturated chains $\big( \lambda^{(0)} \subset \cdots \subset \lambda^{(n)} \big)$ and  $\big(\mu^{(0)} \subset \cdots \subset \mu^{(n)} \big)$
in the Young Lattice with $\lambda^{(0)} = \mu^{(0)}= \emptyset$ as well as $\lambda^{(n)}= \lambda$ and $\mu^{(n)}=\mu$ then $T \unlhd S$ if and only if $\lambda^{(k)} \unlhd \mu^{(k)}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Apologies.

thanks, ines.

Comment: The number of order ideals in $\Lambda_n$ doesn't seem to be in OEIS. ([Brute force Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVxrEKg1AMBdC9X5ExAXEuzl2c7B9I0FQCzxvJy_9TPdP5RRLIQak4jN8yveh2paMYAzUDX9Gt-jij7LD8apaXB_onTodisyV3S4aM8WT13bT1tWmVb8Yi8gf5dyPQ&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==); [checking OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C6%2C8%2C14%2C20&sort=&language=english&go=Search).)

Comment: Involutions might not be in bijection with partitions, but cycle types of permutations are, so the second question isn't as misguided as you make it look. (Though I wouldn't bet on it having a good answer either...)